# How to load <img> tag SRC into a javascript variable to be re-used across multiple images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-processing, src

So here is my plan for fast web page downloading...

1. Place all images into a single png-24 image sprite.
2. Encode that image as base64 and include it in the webpage HTML code.
3. Duplicate the SRC of the original image sprite and re-use it for the logo, share buttons, other images, etc..

The only problem I can foresee is the duplication of the base64 encoded image source.

Can I readily extract the image source with jQuery and just re-insert it into all of my blank images (the images that need the sprite to be created)?

EDIT: Some people are mentioning base64 images are not cached, but wouldn't my entire webpage (containing the base64 images) be cached if I told it to be?

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way - load the image into a DOM element. You can then clone that element as many times as necessary.

Comment: Care to explain how I might do that? I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "load the image into a DOM element".

Comment: Most probably he meant just use a standard `<img/>` tag, which you can clone and use freely using jQuery / Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a common technique with CSS icons / reusable images.

You can get the image `src` using `$(element).attr('src');`.

However, I don't see the advantage of encoding the image binary (I'm assuming you meant the image file itself) to base64 to include with the HTML markup. You may be over-thinking this a bit.

I don't think you can "save" bytes by re-encoding the image data into base 64, primarily because base 64 is a narrower character set than the encoding used in the original data (think binary `111` = decimal `7`), so I expect a larger output actually. (But that's just me theorycrafting, so correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, if you do manage, for example, to re-encode to at most an equal size of markup, then you're not making any headway with "faster downloading". You're still downloading the same amount of data. Most probably more.

If you do manage a smaller payload, is the performance hit of encoding / re-encoding worth it? Not to mention the cross-browser compatibility.

A better technique would be to package the images into a single image file (which is the spirit of your exercise), and just let the browser download that as normal. Once one copy of an image is downloaded, as long as its cached by the browser, it won't download it anymore.

#### EDIT

To answer your edit regarding caching of the web pages, yes, your web pages will be cached. So will your base-64 encoded images. But since your images are effectively part of the HTML markup, they're going to be cached **with** the HTML pages.

e.g. If I download `foo.html` (which includes my encoded sprite file), I'm definitely going to get my markup as normal. That page is cached.

Now, I download `bar.html` (which uses my sprite file too). I expect that your image won't be cache-accessible from `bar.html`, because as far as the browser is concerned, that image is part of the HTML markup of `foo.html`. It probably won't even realize that there's an image wedged in there.

The way caching works (as best I can understand it) is **URL matching**. That's the reason why if I download `facepalm.jpg` in one page, and request `facepalm.jpg` again in another, the browser recognizes that I've already downloaded it, so it doesn't.

With your encoding plan, I'm not going to be requesting `foo.html` (or part of it) from `bar.html`, so I expect that your image caching won't work as you expect it to in your question.

If I visit `foo.html` *again* though, I'd get all benefits of caching for that page, as I've "downloaded that before".

Comment: I wouldn't be saving any bytes, no. But I would be saving an extra HTTP call to my webserver for the image file. Lessening the load on both my server and the client's machine. It's what google does for all of their google.com pages at least, check the source code, I assume they know what they're doing :P

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. I'm feel that it should be noted that Google is more or less justified in attempting that, due to the sheer amount of hits their server gets. Milking payload savings to the last drop --- as for us (relatively) petty folk, however, I'd reckon a second thought on doing that. :) But hey, if you want manage it, why not.

Comment: One caveat I see with that though is that you'll have to include the encoded sprite file **on every page that uses it** (unless you can cache it somehow, which I doubt. Correct me if I'm wrong though.) to consider it "cached". Barring that, you're effectively downloading the same image every single page load. Google can get away with it because they're practically just two pages, with a small image payload. Again, some more stuff to think about.

Comment: Yes, base64-encoded files **will** be 33% larger than the original, guaranteed.  Yes, the encoded sprite has to be included (and thus re-downloaded) on each page.  I've added [some more comments as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197746/201952).

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan I just saw your edit, interesting... I never thought about that. Perhaps I could include the base64 data inside the css files to save space on each page? Hrmm.. looks like I have some tradeoffs to make.

Comment: @darkAsPitch ~ that, or just load the image file normally. haha. :D whatever floats your boat, I suppose. Personally though, I'm still not convinced base64-ing is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, a better plan is to use a single image with many sprites, then use the

```
background: url(...)
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

attributes in CSS. That way you only ever load 1 image, which DOES cache.

Comment: Right, I plan on using a single image. But how do I duplicate the image source across multiple img tags? I don't want to load the image URL in a separate HTTP call, I want to load it via base64 in the webpage.

Comment: @darkAsPitch, you can use the same url straight in the img tag - there won't be multiple http requests if it's the same image. The browser checks whether it's already got the image in the cache first.

Comment: Ok fair enough, as for caching though... wouldn't the entire HTML webpage be cached if my web server told it to be? I want to use base64 to avoid the extra HTTP call.

Comment: No, the BROWSER caches the image and just uses the present data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `var imgSrc = $("#yourImage").attr("src");` and then use `$("img").attr("src", imgSrc);` to accomplish what you're asking for.

I'm not sure encoding it to base64 is the best option, as base64 images don't get cached, so it would be reloaded every page visit. And it's pretty widely accepted now that base64 encoding adds about 33% to file size.

Read more: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to

Answer (score 1):

I think the base64 thing is a bad idea.  Just load the sprite normally.

Don't blindly look to eliminate all possible HTTP requests at any expense.  (Even if "it's what Google does.")  Achieving good performance is a balancing act, and given the differences between browsers, it's slightly more of an art than it is science.

Reasons you don't want to do this:

- Your image sprite will not be cached *across pages* – in other words, you must transfer the entire image on *every* page.  Assuming a separately served image has proper caching headers, subsequent page requests will be slower and waste bandwidth.
- Base 64 encoding is by its nature wasteful of bandwidth.  A base64-encoded file **will** be 33% larger than the original.  This doesn't matter so much for files a couple kilobytes large, but this will be a big problem for large files, like your image sprite.
- As you've realized, you'd have to duplicate the base64-encoded sprite in every `<img>` tag on your page, which is extremely wasteful, and fixing this via script brings us to...
- Your images become dependent on JavaScript, which is a bad idea.  What if a script doesn't load?  JavaScript is turned off?
- Eliminating this image HTTP request doesn't actually accomplish much in terms of how long before your page is displayed, because images don't block DOM ready.  What's important is reducing HTTP requests for content that does block rendering: scripts and CSS.  (In most cases, one request each.)  Your page does not render at all until script and CSS is fully loaded.  However, the page does render (albeit with empty space) before images download.
- You need to balance the type of images with number HTTP request.  Icons and such generally should be sprited in a PNG so that as many images as possible download in one HTTP request.  Anything photographic in nature needs to go into *its own* JPEG.  **Do not use PNG for pictures.**  It is the wrong compression algorithm, and will result in files 1000% larger than a comparable JPEG.